# How do i write a loadtxt script without using numpy?

Tags: python

I've got an assignment where I am to write a script that sorts numbers from a 'txt' file to a matrix in python.
I know that there is something called numpy in Python but the task is to write my own code for it.

I literally don't even know where to start, I am an ultra-noob to Python.
Please somebody help

This is what the code looks like now:

```
def loadtxt(f):

   m = []
   with open(f,"r",encoding="utf-8") as txt:
       for line in txt:
          vals = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
          m.append(vals)

for x in m :
    print(x)
```

And the files txt files  I am trying to read are sorted in this manner:

```
    12.5            81
    15.27778        97
    17.5            103
    19.72222        123
    22.2222         150
    25.83333        182
    28.3333         195
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the .txt has it's values space-separated like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

I also assume, by array you mean Python lists. In that case, the code for this problem is:

```
m = []
```

```
with open("test.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as txt:
    for line in txt:
       vals = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
       m.append(vals)

for x in m :
    print(x)
```

The output of the for loop is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
```

If the Matix-values are separated with another Character, just put that as a Parameter in the split-Function.

**EDIT**

Following your edited Data, i assume, you just need a List that goes:

```
12.5, 15.27778, 17.5, 19.72222, 22.2222, 25.83333, 28.3333, 81, 97, etc.
```

In that case, you can edit the provided Code like follows:

```
with open("test.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as txt:
for line in txt:
   vals = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
   m.extend(vals)

for x in m.sorted():
   print(x)
```

the Output of the last For-loop would be the List, provided at the start of the Edit.